# rollover and image change after move-out false

Tags: jquery, css

With this code a toggle a Div and change an arrow-img to up or down-image. The first Div is per default open, the second close. My problem is, that if I click on the image of the first div to close it, the image/div changed but if I move the mouse out of the image, it change back to the default values. How can I change that?

```js
var org_src;
$("img.mgu-rollover").hover(
  function() {
    org_src = this.src;
    this.src = $(this).attr("data-rolloverImage");
  },
  function() {
    this.src = org_src;
  }
);

$('.mgu-event-btn').click(function() {
  var open = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('#' + open).toggle().toggleClass("active");
  if ($('#' + open).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'img/Pikto_Bubble_up_off.png');
    $(this).find('img').attr('data-rolloverImage', 'img/Pikto_Bubble_up_over.png');

  } else {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'img/Pikto_Bubble_down_off.png');
    $(this).find('img').attr('data-rolloverImage', 'img/Pikto_Bubble_down_over.png');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mgu-event-btn" rel="mgu-event-1">
  <img class="mgu-rollover" data-rolloverImage="img/Pikto_Bubble_up_over.png" src="img/Pikto_Bubble_up_off.png" width="30" height="30">
</div>

<div class="mgu-event-btn" rel="mgu-event-2">
  <img class="mgu-rollover" data-rolloverImage="img/Pikto_Bubble_down_over.png" src="img/Pikto_Bubble_down_off.png" width="30" height="30">
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. Please get some images from placeholder.it or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is of course  `this.src = org_src;`  which you might want to not do if image had been clicked -

```
function() { 
  if (this.src.indexOf("down")==-1) this.src = org_src;
}
```

for example

Comment: thnks, you brought me on the write way;-)